# How can i generate temporary token in agora for video calling web SDK?

Tags: agora.io, videocall

I want to generate temporary token in agora for video calling web SDK using API.

I searched about this on google, but didn't find anything related to that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to generate token for **Agora Video Calling**

1. **Through Agora Console**

- Navigate to your project on Agora Console
- Click Config
- Go to Features
- Select Generate Temp Token and enter channel name
- Finish

[image]

2. **Through native code in Java, Node etc which can be further used in your Rest Api**

**For Example in Java**

```
RtcTokenBuilder appToken = new RtcTokenBuilder();
        int timestamp = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + Constants.get().RTC_TOKEN_EXPIRE_TIMESTAMP);
        token = appToken.buildTokenWithUserAccount(Constants.get().AGORA_APP_ID, Constants.get().AGORA_APP_CERTIFICATE, Constants.get().AGORA_CHANNEL_NAME, "", RtcTokenBuilder.Role.Role_Publisher, timestamp);
```

- refer to this link for this https://docs.agora.io/en/interactive-live-streaming/develop/integrate-token-generation?platform=web